# Opposite of Flutter's describeEnum function

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

Flutter's [foundation library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/foundation-library.html) has a [describeEnum](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/describeEnum.html) function that returns a short description based on an enum value.

Is there a function that would do the opposite, i.e., return enum value based on the received description?

I know about the [enum_to_string](https://pub.dev/packages/enum_to_string), but I'm interested in vanilla Dart or Flutter standard library solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the `firstWhere` function on the values of your enum:

`MyEnum myEnum = MyEnum.values.firstWhere((e) => describeEnum(e) == str);`

Comment: @F Perroch A great idea, thanks! I'll wait a bit to get more answers, but if nothing better comes, I'll definitely accept yours!